# Почему не вызывается деструктор при возвращении объекта из функции?

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

```
class myclass {
public:
    int* ptr;
    int get() { return *ptr; }
    ~myclass() { 
        free(ptr);
        ptr = nullptr;  
        std::cout << "destruct" << std::endl;

    };
     myclass() { 
         std::cout << "default"<< std::endl;
         ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
         *ptr=999;
     };
     myclass(const myclass&) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; };
};

myclass func()
{
    myclass a;
    cout << "func: " << a.get() << endl;
    cout << "func addr: " << a.ptr << endl;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    myclass a= func();
    cout << "main: " << a.get() << endl;
    cout << "func addr: " << a.ptr << endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
defolt
func: 999
func addr: 000001AF1E7CEF90
main: 999
func addr: 000001AF1E7CEF90
destruct
```

Хотел наглядно спроектировать неприятную ситуацию,когда из функции возвращаем стандартным конструктором копирования объект,после чего освобождается память и объект теперь ссылается на недействительную память,но в функции func() почему то не вызывается деструктор.Более того,почему то не вызывается даже конструктор копирования.Почему?

Comment: В приведенном коде создается только один объект, причем посредством конструктора по-умолчанию и с выделением места под него в `main`.

Comment: Я же кидал вчера ссылку уже https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision. Почему не прочитали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что тут

```
myclass a = func();
```

нет копирования. `func` сразу создает объект `a` в `main` (вечно путаю, как это правильно называется... copy elision, кажется... но начиная с какого-то С++ такое поведение обязательное).

Дополните код выводом адреса `a`:

```
myclass func()
{
    myclass a;
    cout << "a: " << &a << endl;
    cout << "func: " << a.get() << endl;
    cout << "func addr: " << a.ptr << endl;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    myclass a= func();
    cout << "a: " << &a << endl;
    cout << "main: " << a.get() << endl;
    cout << "func addr: " << a.ptr << endl;
}
```

У меня получается

```
a: 000000B74151FDD8
func: 999
func addr: 000002B2AB5AD830
a: 000000B74151FDD8
main: 999
func addr: 000002B2AB5AD830
```

так что, как видите, `a` оlин и тот же и в `func`, и в `main`.

**Update**

Ага, таки немного соврал. Это вроде бы NRVO, и является не обязательной оптимизацией, в отличие от RVO. Смотрите тут - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: получается это обычная оптимизация для того чтобы лишний раз не вызывать конструкторов?

Comment: Не обычная, а стандартизированная :)

Comment: Читаю щас Шилдта, и он ничего не написал об этом поведении,обратно, он написал что будет вызвано 2 деструктора

Comment: Когда он писал?... Тут я немного плаваю - в смысле строгостей стандарта, что именно стандартизовано, могу и соврать ненароком, тогда это просто оптимизация.. Но с вашим не копирующим конструктором копирования оно и к лучшему :)

Comment: некопирующий конструктор тут просто для примера,чтоб показать что он не вызывается

Comment: если читать книги десятилетней давности, то ещё и не такое можно прочитать. А с 17 плюсов вообще ввели temorary materialization - и количество вызовов конструкторов-деструкторов резко сократилось