# Почему не вызывается конструктор копирования при инициализации переменной другим объектом?

Tags: c++

Понимаю что исходный код достаточно большой, но все же, надеюсь кто то да подскажет.
Пытаюсь разобраться с кодом из книги Lippman С++ Primer, конец 15 главы.
Возможно я что то неправильно понимаю, но почему в `main` в строке:

```
Query query = Query("she") & Query("is");
```

копирующий конструктор Query вызывается всего 2 раза при вызове конструктора `BinaryQuery`, когда происходит инициализация `lhs` и `rhs`, но не вызывается когда собственно инициализируется переменная `query` в функции `main`?
Собственно и не могу понять каким образом инициализируется эта переменная если не при помощи копирующего конструктора.

Как я понял, алгоритм выполнения следующий:

1. Создается файловый поток
2. Создается объект класса `TextQuery`
3. Вызывается конструктор `Query(string)` с аргументом `"she"` (внутри вызывается `WordQuery(string)`)
4. Вызывается конструктор `Query(string)` с аргументом `"is"` (внутри вызывается `WordQuery(string)`)
5. Вызывается оператор `&` с двумя аргументами
6. Вызывается конструктор `AndQuery` в который передаются оба операнда
7. Вызывается конструктор `BinaryQuery` в котором происходит инициализация lhs и rhs с помощью копирующего конструктор `Query`
8. Далее вызывается конструктор `Query` с параметром `shared_ptr`, после чего q ссылается на AndQuery объект
9. **И вот тут по моему должен вызываться копирующий конструктор `Query` чтобы произошла инициализация переменной `query` в функции `main`, но почему то этого не происходит...**

**Исходный код:**

```
using namespace std;

class QueryResult
{
public:
    using line_no = vector<string>::size_type;
    QueryResult(string sw, shared_ptr<set<line_no>> ln, shared_ptr<vector<string>> ft) : sought_word(sw), lines_numbers(ln), file_text(ft) {}
    auto begin() const { return lines_numbers->begin(); }
    auto end() const { return lines_numbers->end(); }
    auto get_file() const { return file_text; }
private:
    string sought_word;
    shared_ptr<set<line_no>> lines_numbers;
    shared_ptr<vector<string>> file_text;
};

class TextQuery
{
public:
    using line_no = vector<string>::size_type;
    TextQuery(ifstream& is) : file_text(new vector<string>)
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(is, line))
        {
            file_text->push_back(line);
            istringstream line_stream(line);
            string word;
            while (line_stream >> word)
            {
                auto& lines_numbers = words_map[word];
                if (!lines_numbers) lines_numbers.reset(new set<line_no>);
                lines_numbers->insert(file_text->size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    QueryResult query(const string& sought_word) const
    {
        static shared_ptr<set<line_no>> no_data(new set<line_no>);
        auto loc = words_map.find(sought_word);
        if (loc == words_map.end()) return QueryResult(sought_word, no_data, file_text);
        else return QueryResult(sought_word, loc->second, file_text);
    }
private:
    shared_ptr<vector<string>> file_text;
    map<string, shared_ptr<set<line_no>>> words_map;
};

class QueryBase
{
    friend class Query;
protected:
    using line_no = TextQuery::line_no;
    virtual ~QueryBase() = default;
private:
    virtual QueryResult eval(const TextQuery&) const = 0;
    virtual string rep() const = 0;
};

class Query
{
    friend Query operator~(const Query&);
    friend Query operator|(const Query&, const Query&);
    friend Query operator&(const Query&, const Query&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Query&);
public:
    Query(const string&);
    Query(const Query& query)
    {
        cout << "Here..." << endl;
        q = query.q;
    }
    QueryResult eval(const TextQuery& t) const { return q->eval(t); }
    string rep() const { return q->rep(); }
private:
    Query(shared_ptr<QueryBase> query) : q(query) {}
    shared_ptr<QueryBase> q;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Query& query)
{
    return os << query.rep();
}

class WordQuery : public QueryBase
{
    friend class Query;
private:
    WordQuery(const string& s) : query_word(s) {}
    QueryResult eval(const TextQuery& t) const { return t.query(query_word); }
    string rep() const { return query_word; }
    string query_word;
};

inline Query::Query(const string& s) : q(new WordQuery(s)) {}

class BinaryQuery : public QueryBase
{
protected:
    BinaryQuery(const Query& l, const Query& r, string s) : lhs(l), rhs(r), op_sym(s) {}
    string rep() const { return "(" + lhs.rep() + " " + op_sym + " " + rhs.rep() + ")"; }
    Query lhs;
    Query rhs;
    string op_sym;
};

class AndQuery : public BinaryQuery
{
    friend Query operator&(const Query&, const Query&);
    AndQuery(const Query& left, const Query& right) : BinaryQuery(left, right, "&") {}
    QueryResult eval(const TextQuery& text) const
    {
        auto left = lhs.eval(text);
        auto right = rhs.eval(text);
        auto ret_lines = make_shared<set<line_no>>();
        set_intersection(left.begin(), left.end(), right.begin(), right.end(), inserter(*ret_lines, ret_lines->begin()));
        return QueryResult(rep(), ret_lines, left.get_file());
    }
};

inline Query operator&(const Query& lhs, const Query& rhs)
{
    auto temp = shared_ptr<QueryBase>(new AndQuery(lhs, rhs));
    return Query(temp);
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file("./file.txt");
    TextQuery text_query(file);
    Query query = Query("she") & Query("is"); // ???????????????????????
    print(cout, query.eval(text_query));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175793/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1175795#1175795

Comment: [RVO и NRVO в C++17](https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/666330/)